# How can I allow people to 'subscribe' to categories?

Tags: categories, tags

I would like for people to be able to subscribe to categories and tags, somewhat like Pinterest or Quora where you have to follow a minimum number of categories.

After doing a plugin search, I can't seem to find anything that's been previously developed. Is there anything you can recommend?

Ultimately this will be used send people email updates when new items are posted in a specific category / tag, and, as well, they will optionally be able to set their home page content to show only these content from "followed" categories when logged in.

Thanks!

Comment: Add `/feed/` on the end of the category link. [Like this](http://wordpress.org/news/category/releases/feed/).

Comment: I thought about feeds as well, but, well, is this not for a feeds importer or feeds reader? Please see this link: http://www.trippy.com/destination/Colombia There is a 'follow destination' link to the right of 'Colombia QnA.'  Basically, Colombia is the tag and, by clicking that link, your home page has content you've subscribed to as well as email alerts sent when new content is added. Ultimately, that's what I'm trying to achieve, and I'm hoping to not have to reinvent the wheel. Although, I'm not opposed to a PHP solution if someone would suggest how to get started with that route.